# How do I bind a specific mouse button click with Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

Sorry for the novice question, but I can't see this in the documentation anywhere:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

```
<div>
    You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
        incrementClickCounter : function() {
            var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
            this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
        }
    };
</script>
```

What if I want different actions depending on if the left, right or middle mouse buttons are clicked? Is there a specific binding for it, or do you hook into the event and use event.which or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SJPhe/) Here the right button is bind, you can do this via `data-bind="event: { contextmenu: incrementClickCounter }"`
The middle mouse I haven't figured this out yet. Hope this answer helps you along the way. Let me know what you think ;)

HTML:

```
<div>
    You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>
    <button data-bind="event: { contextmenu: incrementClickCounter }">Click me</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = {
        numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
        incrementClickCounter : function() {
            var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
            this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
        }
    };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks Leroy, I have the middle mouse working inside a function by using if (event.which === 2) { // middle }, not sure if that's the correct way to do it though

Comment: If it works why not ;) You could also take a look at [link]http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html and create your own bindings!